# Show compactness

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a metric space, $K\subseteq X$ be compact and $C\subseteq X$ be closed. Use the definition to show that $K\cap C$ is compact.

I am unsure as to which "definition" the question refers to. I think it has to do with the Heine-Borel Theorem [A subset of $\mathbb R^m$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded] but I am not sure.
I have attempted it by using the fact that $C$ is closed (and therefore bounded), so $K\cap C$ must also be closed (and bounded), but I don't know where to go after this or how to show it topologically

Comment: This is not the general definition -- Heine—Borel theorem does not apply to general metric spaces. The definition of copmpact is "$K$ is compact iff every open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover." (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Definitions))

Comment: Additionally, why would the statement "$C$ is closed **(and therefore bounded)** hold? This is clearly not true in general: $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set (in the topological space $\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to do.

Let $A_\alpha$ be an open cover of $C$. Adjoin $C^c$ to this open cover, where $C^c$ denotes the complement of $C$.

We now have an open cover of $K$. However, since $K$ is compact, then there is a finite cover of $K$.

Remove $C^c$ from this finite cover if it is in it, and then you have a finite covering from $A_\alpha$.